# Given a PPID, how to find all of associated PID?

Tags: linux, monitoring, status, pid

It might be a weird question as I searched and found many people asking about how to find the PPID given a PID. However, I'm interested in finding out all the PID of a given PPID.

The incentive was to run a process check using pidstat and from my test with pidstat, it seems to be that pidstat only reports meaningful child process stats and if I have a driver script and I want to access each individual processes within the driver script, I need to htop and find out the PIDs individually. When I invoked a driver script, such as bash script.sh, there is a ID associated with this command and this ID becames the PPID of all the processes within the driver scripts (if I understand it correctly).

So does anyone know how to get all the PIDs of a PPID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ ps --ppid <YOUR PPID> -o pid=
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pgrep. man pgrep for usage.

```
pgrep -P <ppid>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ ps -x -o pid,ppid | grep -E '[^0-9]{Enter PPID HERE}$'`     # on Mac OS Terminal

.

e.g. if ppid = 1

`$ ps -x -o pid,ppid | grep -E '[^0-9]1$'`     # on Mac OS Terminal